# Insert a paragraph in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm doing a search and replace on a .docx file and in some cases the replace text contains newlines. I've tried a couple of techniques for this. The first was to split the replacement text up into lines and do:

```
run.setText(lines[0], 0);
for (int x = 1; x < lines.length; x++) {
    run.addCarriageReturn();
    run.setText(lines[x]);
}
```

The result all ran together on a single line.

So then I did some hunting and found this code for replacing the existing paragraph with a set of paragraphs per line:

```
private void replaceParagraph(XWPFParagraph p, String[] paragraphs) {
    if (p != null) {
        XWPFDocument doc = p.getDocument();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            XmlCursor cursor = p.getCTP().newCursor();
            XWPFParagraph newP = doc.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
            newP.setAlignment(p.getAlignment());
            newP.getCTP().insertNewR(0).insertNewT(0).setStringValue(paragraphs[i]);
            newP.setNumID(p.getNumID());
        }
        doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(p));
    }
}
```

The problem is that `insertNewParagraph` returns null every time. This might be because the paragraph is inside a table cell, but I haven't isolated that as the cause. I've checked the cursor, and `cursor.isStart()` is true which seems to comply with the requirement from the documentation.

> Add a new paragraph at position of the cursor. The cursor must be on the XmlCursor.TokenType.START tag of an subelement of the documents body. When this method is done, the cursor passed as parameter points to the XmlCursor.TokenType.END of the newly inserted paragraph.

I've double-checked that `doc != null`, and I can't think of any other reason this might return null. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that if I'd just changed run.addCarriageReturn() to run.addBreak() in the simplest form, that would have solved my issue as well. And saved me a day and a half trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

This turned out to solve the issue.

```
private void createParagraphs(XWPFParagraph p, String[] paragraphs) {
    if (p != null) {
        XWPFDocument doc = p.getDocument();
        XmlCursor cursor = p.getCTP().newCursor();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            XWPFParagraph newP = doc.createParagraph();
            newP.getCTP().setPPr(p.getCTP().getPPr());
            XWPFRun newR = newP.createRun();
            newR.getCTR().setRPr(p.getRuns().get(0).getCTR().getRPr());
            newR.setText(paragraphs[i]);
            XmlCursor c2 = newP.getCTP().newCursor();
            c2.moveXml(cursor);
            c2.dispose();
        }
        cursor.removeXml(); // Removes replacement text paragraph
        cursor.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for posting the answer. This is very helpful.